# How can I view a PDF in Firefox when the server specifies the wrong content type?

Tags: firefox, pdf, mime-types

I am using Mozilla Firefox with a PDF viewer plug-in. The plug-in has been correctly associated with Adobe Reader files to view them in the browser in the settings.

I would like to be able to view PDF files in Firefox rather than downloading them. This already works correctly when a web server indicates that a file has the `Content-Type` of `application/pdf`. However, some web servers provide other `Content-Type`s for PDFs, such as `application/octet-stream`. (See [this example of a PDF served with a non-pdf `Content-Type`](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/2/7/C2715F76-F56C-4D37-9231-EF8076B7EC13/userdoc.pdf).)

I have looked at [Firefox's MimeTypes.rdf file](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf), and it appears to only support mapping applications based on file extensions for non-Internet-based files. (It looks like it only uses `Content-Type` to map Internet-based files.)

How can I have Firefox view **all** PDF documents in-browser rather than only the ones with the `application/pdf` `Content-Type`?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has no content inspection code (e.g. the linux `file` command) to detect the actual content type and rely on the `Content-Type` header.

#### Workaround: `mozplugger` extension

See `man 7 mozplugger`:

> ```
>   extensions
>           This is a comma separated list of extensions that should be associated with this particular mime type. The  exten‐
>           sions are only used when a web server does not report what type of file it is, or when loading files directly from
>           disk.
> ```

#### Workaround: human interaction

Save the file and open it in the file explorer ;-)

#### Workaround: misconfiguration

An additional workaround is to hack `mimeTypes.rdf` and assign `application/octet-stream` to the same value as `application/pdf`.

**I don't advice this workaround.**

Comment: The description of the mozplugger extension seems to imply that it only works when the web server doesn't indicate the `Content-Type`. (I use Windows, so it looks like I can't test it.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Force Content-Type](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/force-content-type/) extension for pdf files with wrong `Content-Type` response header.

For example if web server provides `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` you can add rule to transform it to `Content-Type: application/pdf` based on pdf file url, like this:

[image]